# Electron with CodeMirror: Error calling setValue

Tags: javascript, electron, codemirror

I am very new to writing in Electron, and am muddling my way through my first app.

I have a `textarea` which I want to populate with data read from a file:

```
function load(textarea,path) {
    fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
        textarea.value=data;
    });
}

load(…,…);
```

that works, and I have the data.

However, if I use CodeMirror, I get an error:

```
const CodeMirror=require('codemirror');
const editor=CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea,{lineNumbers: true});

function load(textarea,path) {
    fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
        editor.setValue(data);
    });
}

load(…,…);
```

The console give me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: string.split is not a function
```

Obviously, I’m not doing it correctly.

What should I be doing?

Comment: what is `textarea` in `textarea,{lineNumbers: true}` Are you defining the textarea element? Also, what does `data` return?